# problem with flex module full screen

Tags: apache-flex

hi i want to load flex module with width="100%" height="100%" but it doesn't works

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:ns1="*" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%">

<mx:ModuleLoader url="TestModule.swf" >

</mx:ModuleLoader>

</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module
   xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
   layout="absolute"
   percentWidth="100" percentHeight="100">
    <mx:ColumnChart id="columnchart1">
    <mx:series>
        <mx:ColumnSeries displayName="Series 1" yField="" dataProvider="{ [1, 2, 5, 8, 3] }" />
    </mx:series>
</mx:ColumnChart>`</mx:Module>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mx:ModuleLoader url="TestModule.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would surround the Mode with something like a VBOX or a Group which also has 100%, 100% then it works fine for me.